# fragment in layout background not filling entire screen on configuration change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a first layout with a map fragment, which it fills entire screen on a configuration change (orientation) perfectly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.project.MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is when this first layout goes on background in a transparent way. A new second layout with a spinner appears over first one but when the orientation changes the map fragment doesnt fill entire screen. It keeps its width. The second layout with a spinner fills all the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    tools:context="com.example.project.SecondActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advanced! I really would appreciate any help.

EDIT: I'm using `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` in first activity in my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I see the layout of the SecondActivity has match_parent for both dimensions, so when you start the SecondActivity, the MainActivity is send to the back stack and stopped. See this link for more information:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html:
"When an activity stops, the system retains the current state of its user interface." So when the configuration changes, like the orientation, only the SecondActivity is updated since it is the only one being focused and has the entire screen visibility.

Try setting the SecondActivity layout to wrap_content for both dimensions (width and height), so the MainActivity layout will be partially hidden and the Android system will refresh the configuration when required even though SecondActivity is focused.

Also see this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html.
"Paused:
Another activity is in the foreground and has focus, but this one is still visible. That is, another activity is visible on top of this one and that activity is partially transparent or doesn't cover the entire screen. A paused activity is completely alive (the Activity object is retained in memory, it maintains all state and member information, and remains attached to the window manager), but can be killed by the system in extremely low memory situations."
"Stopped:
The activity is completely obscured by another activity (the activity is now in the "background"). A stopped activity is also still alive (the Activity object is retained in memory, it maintains all state and member information, but is not attached to the window manager). However, it is no longer visible to the user and it can be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere."

So the key is don't use "match parent" in the SecondActivity layout and the transparent background over the MainActivity.

Please try it and let me know how it goes! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It does not work either. In fact, I'm using a custom theme for getting transparency too because `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` apparently do nothing. And I want to achieve this. I want to see the spinner (second layout) and still see the map fragment below. I get this, but the problem is when I change the orientation, like I said. Maybe the solution goes for using only one activity and/or one layout.

Comment: Yes, that could work, you can try then using the MainActivity and a custom popup window with transparent background that is not going to take all the screen and still having the MainActivity attached to the window manager. Thanks!